# Why do return codes over 255 return a differnt number in C++?

Tags: c++, return, exit-code

For example...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){return 300;}
```

Returns:

```
Process finished with exit code 44
```

??

Comment: It's only taking 8 bits.  `300 & 0xff == 44`.  Pretty sure this is mostly a Unix thing.  See `WEXITSTATUS` in the `waitpid` manpage - the status is OR'd into some other values.

Comment: could you explain why? and is it possible to return a higher number?

Comment: There is no such thing as a return code over 255. The OS ignores any bits beyond the first eight.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out that this only applies to the return code of the *program*. Obviously non-main functions can return anything they like. Generally program return codes are just used for error handling anyway, so 255 values is plenty (your actual output should typically go to stdout so that it can be piped around)

Comment: The handling of process return codes is going to be operating-system specific and the C++ standard basically just says that the implementation defines what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard knows only two standaradized return values: `EXIT_SUCCESS` (or zero)  and `EXIT_- FAILURE`:

> **3.6.1/5** A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and
>   calling **`std::exit`** with the return value as the argument.
>
> **18.5/8** (...) Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status
>   successful termination is returned. If status is `EXIT_- FAILURE`, an
>   implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is
>   returned. **Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined**.

It is hence not guaranteed that any other integer is returned as is.

On [MS Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx) for example, the [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns the integer value so you'll get 300.

On [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html) compliant systems, like [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), the rule is that (*"only the 8 least significant bits (i.e. status & 0377) shall be available to the awaiting parent process"*).  So for 300, it will be 44.

Comment: Actually, under unix, the exit code is in the MSB, so `(status & 0xff00) >> 8`. The reason for only 8 bits is historical: Under original unix [developed for the PDP-11], an `int` was 16 bits, so no room for a larger error code in `status` for `wait`. For backwards compatibility, the size of the error code was _not_ increased, even though most arches now define `int` as a 32 bit entity. As mentioned, since the code returned by a program goes through the OS and is obtained by the parent from a syscall, it is OS type dependent

Comment: @CraigEstey Interesting, thanks! Indeed I found in "*The design of the unix operating system*" a note explaining that the lower 8 bits passed to `exit()` are stored in the bits 8 to 15 of internal process return code as you said. I suppose that this is the reason why the return code obtained from from [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) must be interpreted correctly with  `WIFEXITED()`, `WEXITSTATUS()` and so on... And the same for the return of [`system()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Comment: Thanks to @HansPassant for the update. In fact the Windows documentation of `exit()` says "*the low-order byte of status is made available to the host environment*",  But test shows that the full integer is always returned, exactly as you have stated in relation to `GetExitCodeProcess()`. This happens even if using the legacy `execlp()`. So it seems that the absence of the word "only" is to be interpreted as "the lowest byte or more" :-)